# Convert String scanner to class type

Tags: java, string, types

I'm a begginner in `Java` and I have a question about convert `String` to a `Class` Type (?).

My main class have this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Inserir 1o nome:");
    String firstname = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Inserir apelido:");
    String lastname = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Inserir género:");
    String gender = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Inserir tipo de funcionário (A, B ou C):");
    String type = scanner.next();
```

But I have to convert last `String` to an enum type:

```
public enum EmployeeType {
    A, 
    B, 
    C
}
```

Any hint?

Comment: Are you trying to Use A/B/C to call functions within the EmplyoeeType mehtod? Or use it to define data?

Comment: Try looking up Enum Types Here is a link [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
String type = scanner.next();
EmployeeType enumType = EmployeeType.valueOf(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch` up to Java7...

```
String type = scanner.next();
EmployeeType eType = EmployeeType.valueOf(type);

switch(eType) {
    case A:
       // do what you need
       break;
    case B:
    // etc...
}
```

Or you can compare with an if

```
if (type.equals(EmployeeType.A.toString()) {
    // do your stuff
} else if (type.equals(EmployeeType.B.toString()) {
    // etc...
}
```